# How to make this function work on an onclick event

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I have this Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$('#ex2').jqm({ajax: 'view.php?id=<?=$objResult["id"];?>', trigger: 'a.ex2trigger'});
});
</script>
```

That requires this HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="ex2trigger">
View
<div class="jqmWindow" id="ex2">
Please wait... <img src="inc/busy.gif" alt="loading" />
</div>
```

How would I integrate this so it works on a table `<tr onclick>` event?  So when you click a row it brings up the corresponding view.php?id=

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would attach an event handler to the table monitoring the clicks on the rows. You then would get the index of that row and pass it to your function.

```
$("table").on('click','tr',function(){
     $('#ex2').jqm({ajax:'view.php?id='+$(this).index(),trigger:'a.ex2trigger'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  However I placed that code in my `<head>` section, and put in my table name and it doesn't recognize row clicks.  I tested it with a simple alert and still nothing.

Comment: Ok. I was a little apprehensive of posting this but here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXG4j/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're AJAX loading the table, you should use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) API of jQuery.

```
$("table tr").live('click', function(){
   $('#ex2').jqm({ajax:'view.php?id='+$(this).index(),trigger:'a.ex2trigger'});
});`
```